# Video as texture in three.js in android

Tags: cordova, three.js

I am trying to create an Android app using Cordova. The web application which I have created uses three.js.

I have a video as texture on one side of a cube. This video is playing perfectly on desktop Chrome {using video.play () function}.

However when I use Cordova to convert it into an apk and run it on my Android phone, the video is not playing.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is with Android not being able to automatically play videos. It needs a user action before video can be started.
https://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/